# YAF Forum 2 questions: make it one level and remove bottom page icons

Tags: c#, asp.net, forum, yetanotherforum

I have installed the open source forum YetAnotherForum on my website.

1) Can I make the forum to be only one level? no categories and only one forum. (The discussions appears direcly on the Home.

2) Is there a way to hide the icons in the bottom of the page?

screenshot:

http://i53.tinypic.com/erfnno.jpg

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of the second question

I put

```
Visible="false"
```

in

```
<YAF:ForumIconLegend ID="IconLegend" runat="server"/>
```

in forum.ascx file